# Significato di "dare sugo" in questo testo

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Solo che quella sera c’era rivista di gala nel ricreatorio del lazzaretto, tutto un programma a sorpresa,
>   con attori e attrici dei nostri: regista unico, trovarobe e
>   buttafuori, il Gran Magro. Costui, difatti, lo avevo scoperto subito dopo il mio arrivo, non era solo in quel luogo il molto potente pontefice dal cui labbro di lepre, dal
>   cui pugno scettrato di stetoscopio, ci toccava aspettare
>   ogni mattina la cresima o il viatico; bensì, nelle ricorrenze dell’anno, il procuratore di collettive letizie: luminarie, quadri animati, presepi, misteri buffi. Uno sfogo come un altro, per noi; per lui, forse, l’intempestiva
>   rivincita di una vocazione, in forza della quale non esitava ora a trascurare i pazienti, a meno che non gli servissero nella baracca delle prove, fra le malve del giardino,
>   in maschera di numi o di paladini. Io non ero della partita, tra loro ero appena arrivato, un novellino. Ma, se
>   non a questa, alla prossima passerella non intendevo
>   mancare; a costo di esibirmi da cartomante o pagliaccio.
>   Il Magro mi capì. L’attesa della morte è una noia come un’altra, e che si nutre di pompe più assai della morte
>   stessa. Dunque lui, com’era solito fare, promise a tutto
>   spiano: per Capodanno, per Carnevale, per Pasqua; per
>   l’altra estate, se ci arrivavo. A sentirlo, aveva già in mente il da farsi, un intreccio di dramma antico (non amava
>   che i classici, lui) da ridurre in versicoli da burla e che
>   parlasse di noi per ambage: un’Alcesti, un Filottete in
>   bombetta, con agnizioni, qui pro quo, e torte sul ceffo
>   bistrato di Tanatos. A questo tema avrei dovuto **dare sugo** io, che sapevo di lettere, e fare per intanto da vice a
>   lui nella scelta e nell’addestramento delle persone dell’opera.

Ho cercato il termine "sugo" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono sicura di capire il senso dell'espressione "dare sugo" nel brano precedente. Una delle accezioni che ho trovato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sugo) è

> Soddisfazione, gusto, piacere che si trae da ciò che si fa o dice, o che da altri è detto o fatto

Quindi, sarebbe "dare soddisfazione"? O si tratterebbe piuttosto del contrario all'accezione che segue?

> locuz. agg. o avv. *senza sugo*, riferita a discorsi, scritti, fatti e situazioni da cui non si ricava nulla: *una commedia, una satira senza s.; gran discorsoni ma senza nessun s.; la sera, per non sentire quelle chiacchiere senza s., si metteva sull’uscio colle spalle al muro* (Verga)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nel passaggio da te citato il significato di dare sugo è quello di dare contenuto, significato, consistenza, esattamente il contrario dell'accezione di Treccani "senza sugo" che hai trovato.

Comment: Si usa anche la locuzione "dare sostanza"